# Display the images vertically center when they are displayed within the holder

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to build a simple photo gallery with jQuery. This is what I have got so far. This works fine but the problem is the photos don't appear vertically centered to the screen.

This is the snippet that I'm working on. If you run the snippet full screen, the images stick to the top. How can I display the images vertically centered when they are displayed within the holder?

```js
//Options
var showNav = 1;
var keyboardNav = 1;
var showCaption = 1;
var loop = 1;

//Create overlay items
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $image = $('<img>');
var $holder = $('<div class="holder"></div>');
var $caption = $('<p></p>');
var $nav = $('<div class="nav"><a id="close" nohref><span>&times;</span></a><a id="prev" nohref><span>&#8592;</span></a><a id="next" nohref><span>&#8594;</span></a></nav>');
var glength = $('#imageGallery li').length;
var imageIndex, imageLocation, captionText, allowKeyboard;

//Add overlay items to DOM
$('#overlay img').before('');
$holder.append( $image );
$holder.append( $nav );
if ( showCaption ){ $holder.append( $caption ); }
if ( !showNav ){ $nav.hide(); }
$overlay.append( $holder );
$("body").append( $overlay );

//Click image link
$('#imageGallery a').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");
 
 // index of clicked item
   imageIndex = $( '#imageGallery a' ).index(this) + 1;

    //Image focused on
    $image.attr("src", imageLocation);
 
 //Add and remove active class on link
 $(this).addClass('active');
 $('#imageGallery a').not(this).removeClass('active');
 
    //Show alt attribute as caption
    captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
    $caption.text(captionText);
   
 allowKeyboard = 1;
    $overlay.show(); 
});

//Close overlay
$image.click(function() {
 allowKeyboard = 0;
 $($overlay).hide();
});

$overlay.click(function(e) {
 if(e.target != this) return;
 $(this).hide();
});

$('#close').click(function() {
 $($overlay).hide();
});
//Cycle images
$('#next').click(function() {
 //check to see if its the last image
 if (glength != imageIndex){
  $('.active').closest('li').next().find('img').trigger('click');
 } else if (loop == 1){
  $('#imageGallery li').first().find('img').trigger('click');
 } 
});

$("body").keydown(function(e) {
 if (keyboardNav == 1 && allowKeyboard == 1) {
   if(e.which == 37) { $('#prev').trigger("click"); }
   else if(e.which == 39) { $('#next').trigger("click"); } 
   else if(e.which == 27) { $($overlay).hide(); } 
 }
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
 //check to see if its the first image 
 if (imageIndex != 1){
  $('.active').closest('li').prev().find('img').trigger('click'); 
 } else if (loop == 1){
  $('#imageGallery li').last().find('img').trigger('click');
 }  
});
```

```css
ul#imageGallery {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  max-width: 780px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul#imageGallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  background: ghostwhite;
  margin: 10px;
}
ul#imageGallery li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul#imageGallery li a img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

#overlay {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#overlay .holder {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#overlay .holder img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}
#overlay .holder p {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
#overlay .holder .nav {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#overlay .holder .nav a {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#overlay .holder .nav a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #next, #overlay .holder .nav #prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 40px;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #next span, #overlay .holder .nav #prev span {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
          transform: translateY(50%);
  position: relative;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #next {
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #prev {
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #close {
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 1000000;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<ul id="imageGallery">
   <li><a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Caption 1"></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/new-years-eve-2018-4995722058399744.2-2xa.gif"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/new-years-eve-2018-4995722058399744.2-2xa.gif" alt="Caption 2"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you'd want to use flexbox to position items; it's the standard thing to do. In the past, you would've had to deal with margins, floats, top/left/right/bottom and/or doing transform:translate.

If using flexbox, you'll also need to adjust how you show/hide your overlay, as jQuery's .show() isn't aware of your desire for "display: flex" instead of "display: block".

See 'EDITED' comments in code.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/EGbKvP)

```js
//Options
var showNav = 1;
var keyboardNav = 1;
var showCaption = 1;
var loop = 1;

//Create overlay items
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $image = $('<img>');
var $holder = $('<div class="holder"></div>');
var $caption = $('<p></p>');
var $nav = $('<div class="nav"><a id="close" nohref><span>&times;</span></a><a id="prev" nohref><span>&#8592;</span></a><a id="next" nohref><span>&#8594;</span></a></nav>');
var glength = $('#imageGallery li').length;
var imageIndex, imageLocation, captionText, allowKeyboard;





//Add overlay items to DOM
$('#overlay img').before('');
$holder.append( $image );
$holder.append( $nav );
if ( showCaption ){ $holder.append( $caption ); }
if ( !showNav ){ $nav.hide(); }
$overlay.append( $holder );
$("body").append( $overlay );

//Click image link
$('#imageGallery a').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");
 
 // index of clicked item
   imageIndex = $( '#imageGallery a' ).index(this) + 1;

    //Image focused on
    $image.attr("src", imageLocation);
 
 //Add and remove active class on link
 $(this).addClass('active');
 $('#imageGallery a').not(this).removeClass('active');
 
    //Show alt attribute as caption
    captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
    $caption.text(captionText);
   
 allowKeyboard = 1;

    // EDITED
    //$overlay.show();
    $('#overlay').addClass('show_flex');
});

//Close overlay
$image.click(function() {
 allowKeyboard = 0;
 $($overlay).hide();
});

$overlay.click(function(e) {
 if(e.target != this) return;
 $(this).hide();
});

$('#close').click(function() {

    // EDITED
 //$($overlay).hide();
    $('#overlay').removeClass('show_flex');
});

//Cycle images
$('#next').click(function() {
 //check to see if its the last image
 if (glength != imageIndex){
  $('.active').closest('li').next().find('img').trigger('click');
 } else if (loop == 1){
  $('#imageGallery li').first().find('img').trigger('click');
 } 
});

$("body").keydown(function(e) {
 if (keyboardNav == 1 && allowKeyboard == 1) {
   if(e.which == 37) { $('#prev').trigger("click"); }
   else if(e.which == 39) { $('#next').trigger("click"); } 
   else if(e.which == 27) { $($overlay).hide(); } 
 }
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
 //check to see if its the first image 
 if (imageIndex != 1){
  $('.active').closest('li').prev().find('img').trigger('click'); 
 } else if (loop == 1){
  $('#imageGallery li').last().find('img').trigger('click');
 }  
});
```

```css
ul#imageGallery {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 780px;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* EDITED */
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul#imageGallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  background: ghostwhite;
  margin: 10px;
}
ul#imageGallery li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul#imageGallery li a img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

#overlay {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* EDITED */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}
#overlay .holder {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#overlay .holder img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}
#overlay .holder p {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
#overlay .holder .nav {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#overlay .holder .nav a {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#overlay .holder .nav a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #next, #overlay .holder .nav #prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 40px;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #next span, #overlay .holder .nav #prev span {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
          transform: translateY(50%);
  position: relative;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #next {
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #prev {
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #close {
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 1000000;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#overlay .holder .nav #close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* EDITED */
.show_flex {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<ul id="imageGallery">
   <li><a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Caption 1"></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/new-years-eve-2018-4995722058399744.2-2xa.gif"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/new-years-eve-2018-4995722058399744.2-2xa.gif" alt="Caption 2"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow! It's perfect. Thanks for the lesson. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use flexbox. Set the parent to:
display: flex;
justify-content: center

Let me know if you insist on non flexbox solution.
But it is the most recommended one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But is it possible to align the image vertically center with the above code that I'm working on?